# Total number of hashes performed for bitcoin purposes?

Tags: hash, hashpower

I would like to estimate the total number of hashes (double SHA-256) that have been performed for bitcoin purposes.

As an estimate, I downloaded [mining stats](https://api.blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate?scale=1&timespan=all&format=csv), massaged the numbers (assuming the rate shown is for the period ending at the date indicated and starting at the date before), came to **201⋅10<sup>24</sup> hashes** (equivalently 2<sup>87.38</sup> or 2<sup>88.38</sup> SHA-256) on Oct 28, 2017.
[**update: 517⋅10<sup>24</sup> hashes** that is 2<sup>88.74</sup> or 2<sup>89.74</sup> SHA-256 by May 4, 2018].

Did I goof badly in that estimation of the hashes used for mining?

What other ***comparably non-negligible*** number of hashes is performed for bitcoin purposes, and how can that be estimated?

Clarifying: I'm looking only for things that represent a sizable fraction of the number of hashes spent for mining, say at least 0.5%; I'm totally willing to ignore the rest.

Comment: The total number of non-mining hashes is many orders of magnitude smaller than the mining hashes; much less than your 0.5%.  So in fact you are going to ignore all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming the numbers in the link are correct**, then I think this would be right.

I got the same result by multiplying every entry by (1,000,000,000,000 * 3600 * 24 * 2) and adding them up. Came out to 2.008E^26.

But the total number of hashes is much higher. Every block in the blockchain is hashed by every client, every transaction is created using several hashes, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks for checking my computations! Isn't it safe to say that the number of hashes performed when _"block in the blockchain is hashed by every client"_ is negligible in comparison? I'm looking at a significant _"etc, etc"_.. Perhaps, for blockchain maintenance/compaction, which remains quite a mystery to me.

Comment: Depends what you consider negligible. A rough Fermi estimation for this number would be for the blockchain (500,000 blocks * 1,000,000 total downloads) = 500,000,000,000 and for transactions (250,000,000,000 * 10,000 clients) = 2,500,000,000,000,000. So small in comparison to the mining hash rate, to be sure, but perhaps not negligible.

Comment: Validating a single block can involve tens or hundreds of thousands of sha256. Every block has a tree of double sha256 leaves, every signature has at least one sha256 possibly multiple.

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you are asking, you might want to include all hashing done on all full nodes as part of the transaction validation as well.